# FragmentStatePagerAdapter getitem issue

Tags: android, fragmentstatepageradapter

I made a photo gallery. Pictures are stored in a directory. 
But if i have 3 pictures in the directory, only 2 are displayed.
getcount returns 3.
I had 3 elements in the listfiles. file names are correct. 
But i seems that getitem is called 2 times with position 0 & 1.

at the line args.putInt(DemoObjectFragment.ARG_OBJECT, i+1);, i try with i, i+1, i-1. ( with i-1 it crashed :) ) but with the rest i have only 2 pictures

```
 public static class DemoCollectionPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter{
    String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "PATH";
    public DemoCollectionPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int i) {
        Fragment fragment = new DemoObjectFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt(DemoObjectFragment.ARG_OBJECT, i+1);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        File f = new File(path);
        final File filePict[] = f.listFiles();
        int nb = filePict.length-1;
        return nb;
    }}
public static class DemoObjectFragment extends Fragment {

    public static final String ARG_OBJECT = "object";

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_collection_object, container, false);

        Bundle args = getArguments();
        String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "PATH";
        File f = new File(path);
        final File filePict[] = f.listFiles();
        if(filePict.length>0) {

                    ((ImageView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.pictgal)).setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filePict[args.getInt(ARG_OBJECT)].toString()));
            rootView.findViewById(R.id.butpict).setTag(filePict[args.getInt(ARG_OBJECT)].toString());
        }
        return rootView;
    }
}
```

Comment: instead of args.putInt(DemoObjectFragment.ARG_OBJECT, i+1);
just use args.putInt(DemoObjectFragment.ARG_OBJECT, i); 
in the getItem method

Comment: I try with i but it's the same it shows me the 2 others

Comment: You have the following line in getCount() method:
filePict.length-1; // Change this to:
filePict.length;

Comment: omg i don't see it :/ ty